# Can the Azure DevOps Migration Tools be used to backup a Boards project's work items?

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

Azure DevOps does not offer a built in way to restore Azure Boards in a project to a specific point in time.  This feature is necessary to protect against catastrophic **user** error.

How can [this tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration) be used to fill this gap?

For example, can I migrate to a "backup" project with the intent of potentially restoring the original from the backup.

I was thinking of having X backup target projects and cycle through them (selecting one each day to migrate/backup to), so that I have X days of backups.

Please provide instructions.

Comment: Added as feature request: https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/issues/747

Answer (score 0):

No, at this time this is not possible.